# Changing preg_replace to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have looked for other results for this case but couldn't fix it myself. I would be thankful if someone can help me with replacing this preg_replace with preg_replace_callback

```
preg_replace("/[-_]([a-z])/e", "ucfirst('\\1')", ucwords($verb));
```

---

```
<?php

/** @see Zang_Exception **/
require_once 'Exception.php';

/** @see Zang_Schemas **/
require_once 'Schemas.php';

/**
 * 
 * A Zang InboundXML wrapper.
 * 
 * Please consult the online documentation for more details.
 * Online documentation can be found at: http://www.zang.io/docs/api/inboundxml/
 * 
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * 
 * @category  Zang Wrapper
 * @package   Zang
 * @author    Nevio Vesic <nevio@zang.io>
 * @license   http://creativecommons.org/licenses/MIT/ MIT
 * @copyright (2012) Zang, Inc. <support@zang.io>
 */

class Zang_InboundXML
{

    /**
     * InboundXML simple xml element container
     * 
     * @var null|SimpleXmlElement
     */
    protected $element;

    /**
     * Current child pointer. Used for nesting validations
     * 
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $_currentChild = null;

    /**
     * Constructs a InboundXML response.
     *
     * @param SimpleXmlElement|array $arg:
     *   - the element to wrap
     *   - attributes to add to the element
     *   - if null, initialize an empty element named 'Response'
     */
    public function __construct($arg = null) {
        switch (true) {
            case $arg instanceof SimpleXmlElement:
                $this->element = $arg;
                $this->_currentChild = strtolower($arg->getName());
                break;
            case $arg === null:
                $this->element = new SimpleXmlElement('<Response/>');
                $this->_currentChild = 'response';
                break;
            case is_array($arg):
                $this->element = new SimpleXmlElement('<Response/>');
                $this->_currentChild = 'response';
                foreach ($arg as $name => $value) {
                    $this->_validateAttribute($name, 'response');
                    $this->element->addAttribute($name, $value);
                }
                break;
            default: throw new Zang_Exception('InboundXML Invalid construction argument');
        }
    }


    /**
     * Converts method calls into InboundXML verbs.
     *
     * @return SimpleXmlElement A SimpleXmlElement
     */
    public function __call($verb, array $args) {

        /** convert verbs input like-this-one to LikeThisOne **/
        $verb = preg_replace("/[-_]([a-z])/e", "ucfirst('\\1')", ucwords($verb));

        /** Let's first go check if the verb exists **/
        $this->_validateVerb(ucfirst($verb));

        /** Let's go validate nesting **/
        $this->_validateNesting(ucfirst($verb));

        list($noun, $attrs) = $args + array('', array());

        if (is_array($noun)) list($attrs, $noun) = array($noun, '');

        $child = empty($noun)
            ? $this->element->addChild(ucfirst($verb))
            : $this->element->addChild(ucfirst($verb), $noun);

        foreach ($attrs as $name => $value) {
            /** Validation of verb attributes **/
            $this->_validateAttribute($name, $verb);
            $child->addAttribute($name, $value);
        }
        return new self($child);

    }


    /**
     * Returns the object as XML.
     *
     * @return string The response as an XML string
     */
    public function __toString() {
        $xml = $this->element->asXml();
        return str_replace(
            '<?xml version="1.0" ?>', 
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>', 
            $xml
        );
    }


    /**
     * Validate existance of the verb. Return true if exists, throw exception
     * if fails.
     * 
     * @param  string $verb
     * @throws Zang_Exception 
     * @return bool
     */
    private function _validateVerb($verb) {
        $schemas = Zang_Schemas::getInstance();

        if(!$schemas->isVerb(ucfirst($verb))) {
            $available_verbs = implode(', ', $schemas->getAvailableVerbs());
            throw new Zang_Exception(
                "Verb '{$verb}' is not a valid InboundXML verb. Available verbs are: '{$available_verbs}'"
            );
        }

        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Validate if previous child allows this verb to be its child.
     * 
     * @param  string  $verb
     * @return boolean
     * @throws Zang_Exception 
     */
    private function _validateNesting($verb) {
        $schemas = Zang_Schemas::getInstance();

        if(!$schemas->isNestingAllowed(ucfirst($this->_currentChild), ucfirst($verb))) {
            $nestable_verbs = implode(', ', $schemas->getNestableByVerbs(ucfirst($this->_currentChild)));
            $current_verb   = ucfirst($this->_currentChild);
            $next_verb      = ucfirst($verb);
            throw new Zang_Exception(
                "InboundXML element '{$current_verb}' does not support '{$next_verb}' element. The following elements are supported: '{$nestable_verbs}'."
            );
        }

        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Validate if attribute of verb exists. If not, throw exception, otherwise, return true.
     * 
     * @param  string $attr
     * @param  string $verb
     * @return boolean
     * @throws Zang_Exception 
     */
    private function _validateAttribute($attr, $verb) {
        $schemas = Zang_Schemas::getInstance();

        if(!$schemas->isValidAttribute($attr, ucfirst($verb))) {
            $verb_attribuges = implode(', ', $schemas->getAvailableAttributes(ucfirst($verb)));
            throw new Zang_Exception(
                "Attribute '{$attr}' does not exist for verb '{$verb}'. Available attributes are: '{$verb_attribuges}'"
            );
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer to this without you telling what it actually is you want to do, so _why_ you want to use another function.

Comment: I have added the whole page so you can see exactly

Comment: Why don't you simply tell us the reason?

Comment: @arkascha your method fixed the issue for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear *why* you want to use another function. It *might* be this is because you are upgrading php and the `e` modifier is not supported any more. And the example code you posted *suggest* that you are trying to turn hyphen and underscore concatenated expressions into camel case...

Take a look at this simple demonstration:

```
<?php
$verb = 'this is a simple-test_sentence to convert.';
echo preg_replace_callback(
    "/[-_]([a-z]+)/",
    function($string) { return ucfirst($string[1]); },
    ucwords($verb)
);
```

The output obviously is:

> This Is A SimpleTestSentence To Convert.